# Bitbucket Pipelines - No Application Version named found

Tags: bitbucket, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm trying to deploy `django` project to elasticbeanstalk using bitbucket pipelines.

Here's my config

```
image: python:3.7.2

pipelines:
  branches:
      master:
        - step:
            script: 
              - pipe: atlassian/aws-elasticbeanstalk-deploy:0.2.5
                variables:
                  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
                  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
                  AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
                  APPLICATION_NAME: $APPLICATION_NAME
                  COMMAND: $COMMAND
                  ENVIRONMENT_NAME: $ENVIRONMENT_NAME
                  VERSION_LABEL: ${ENVIRONMENT_NAME}_${BITBUCKET_COMMIT:0:8}_(YYYY-mm-dd_HHMMSS)
                  WAIT: 'true'
              - pip3 install -r requirements.txt
              - python3 manage.py makemigrations
              - python3 manage.py migrate
              - python3 manage.py collectstatic
```

I get the following error :

```
An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the UpdateEnvironment operation: No Application Version named 'production_d095cbe2_YYYY-mm-dd_HHMMSS)' found.
```

I'm just wondering, shouldn't it have year and time frame instead of the `YYYY-mm-dd_HHMMSS`?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you want the date and time you can invoke the [`date`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/date) function of the underlaying linux container:

```
date +"%Y-%m-d_%H%M%S" # displays 2019-03-26_223932
```

So your `bitbucket-piplines.yml` should do what you expect written this way:

image: python:3.7.2

```
pipelines:
  branches:
      master:
        - step:
            script: 
              - pipe: atlassian/aws-elasticbeanstalk-deploy:0.2.5
                variables:
                  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
                  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
                  AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
                  APPLICATION_NAME: $APPLICATION_NAME
                  COMMAND: $COMMAND
                  ENVIRONMENT_NAME: $ENVIRONMENT_NAME
                  VERSION_LABEL: ${ENVIRONMENT_NAME}_${BITBUCKET_COMMIT:0:8}_$(date +"%Y-%m-d_%H%M%S")
                  WAIT: 'true'
              - pip3 install -r requirements.txt
              - python3 manage.py makemigrations
              - python3 manage.py migrate
              - python3 manage.py collectstatic
```

Comment: Found the error, it's the command that's the issue here. Instead of all, I was only `deploying` where there's not the previous version to deploy. Hence the error

Comment: @silverFoxA Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @OmarShabab the variable “command” have the value as all instead of deploy